# Empty image in QClipboard

Tags: qt, clipboard

I am trying to get an image from the clipboard using this code. I click on the "copy image" button in Google Chrome and then press "Shift + Insert" in my application, I get to the first branch of the if-statement and see "QRect (0,0 0x0)" in the console. Only after I press "Shift + Insert" several times - the image will appear - QRect(0,0 1280x720).

uname -a
Linux max-pc 5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 13:29:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

What am i doing wrong? regards, max

```
void CanvasScene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->key()) {
    case (Qt::Key_Insert):
        if (event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) {
            pasteFromClipboard();
        }
    break;
    default:
        QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent(event);
    break;
    }
}

void CanvasScene::pasteFromClipboard()
{
    const QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    const QMimeData *mimedata = clipboard->mimeData();

    if (mimedata->hasImage()) {
        LOG_DEBUG(logger, "IMAGE");
        QImage image = clipboard->image(QClipboard::Clipboard);//qvariant_cast<QImage>(mimedata->imageData());
        qDebug()<<image.rect();
    } else if (mimedata->hasText()) {
        LOG_DEBUG(logger, "TEXT: ", mimedata->text().toStdString());
    } else {
        LOG_DEBUG(logger, "CANNOT DISPLAY DATA");
    }
}
```

Comment: In simple words: that hasImage returns True does not imply that there is a valid QImage, in the case of google-chrome it gives an html where the url of the image is so you will have to parse the html, obtain the url and download it.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks. I've already thought about it. but I thought the code I wrote above would work

Comment: @eyllanesc I wonder why the picture appears later...